# Java - Deserialize a JSON with random root elements without key names

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I receiving the following JSON as a response from a rest api call:

```
{
   "RandomTextA" : {
      "Name" : "Test1",
      "Host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "Port" : 435
   },
   "RandomTextB" : {
      "Name" : "Test2",
      "Host" : "123.10.10.4",
      "Port" : 435
   },
    ...
}
```

Root element values ("RandomTextA", "RandomTextB") are random and prior to the call unkown and could be anything, so i can not use these values to try and parse the JSON or create POJO classes for the root items.

I would like to deserialize it as a Map or List of objects.

My issue is that the root elements of the JSON array do not have a key names and i am searching a way to have something similar to a C# Dictionary to be able and store each array of objects into a searchable <String, Object> Dictionary or Map.

The objective is to be able and traverse the JSON tree by its root elements (RandomTextA, RandomTextB).

Here is my POJO class for the items under the root element(s):

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "Name",
    "Port",
    "Host"
})
public class InnerEntity implements Serializable {
    
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String Name;
    
    @JsonProperty("Port")
    private String Port;
    
    @JsonProperty("Host")
    private String Host;  
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    public InnerEntity(){        
    }
    
    public InnerEntity(String Name,String Port,String Host,String Manufacturer,Boolean AllowEcho,Boolean AllowFind,Boolean AllowMove,Boolean AllowStore){
        super();
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Port = Port;
        this.Host = Host;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Port")
    public String getPort() {
        return Port;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Port")
    public void setPort(String Port) {
        this.Port = Port;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Host")
    public String getHost() {
        return Host;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Host")
    public void setHost(String Host) {
        this.Host = Host;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the api call:

```
public String GetEntities() {
        
        String entities = null;
        
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        if(IS_AUTH_REQ == true) {
            HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            clientConfig.register(feature);
        }
        
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
        WebTarget target = client.target(BASE_URL)
                .path("entities")
                .queryParam("expand","");
        Response response =
                target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .get();
        
        if(response.getStatus() == 200) {
            
            String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
            //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            //entities = mapper.readValue(output, InnerEntity[].class);
            entities = output;
            
        } else {
                LOG.info("# No entities found.");
        }
        
        return entities;
    }
```

I can achieve what is needed in C# in a pretty straightforward and easy way:

```
List<Dictionary<string, InnerEntity>> entities= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, InnerEntity>>>(response);
```

How can i deserialize the JSON in a similar way in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the widely used library **FasterXML / jackson** for this purpose. ([Link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)) See the function "parseJsonToTypedMap()" in code example below, for how to parse your JSON-String to 'Map<String, InnerEntity>' object. (Map is in Java the same as Dictionary in C#).
If you don't want a typed Map, and really just a 'Map<String, Object> object, than look at function "parseJsonToNotTypedMap()".

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class JsonTest {

    String JSON_SOURCE = 
        "{" +
            "\"RandomTextA\" : {" +
                "\"Name\" : \"Test1\","+
                "\"Host\" : \"127.0.0.1\","+
                "\"Port\" : 435" +
            "},"+
            "\"RandomTextB\" : {"+
                "\"Name\" : \"Test2\","+
                "\"Host\" : \"123.10.10.4\","+
                "\"Port\" : 435"+
            "}" +
        "}";
    
    public static class InnerEntity implements Serializable {
        
        @JsonProperty("Name")
        private String Name;
        
        @JsonProperty("Port")
        private String Port;
        
        @JsonProperty("Host")
        private String Host;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "InnerEntity [Name=" + Name + ", Port=" + Port + ", Host=" + Host + "]";
        }
    }
    
    public Map<String, InnerEntity> parseJsonToTypedMap(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        TypeReference typedRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, InnerEntity>>() { };
        
        return (Map<String, InnerEntity>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes()), 
                typedRef);
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> parseJsonToNotTypedMap(String json) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        return (Map<String, Object>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
    }
    
    public void runTest() {
        
        try {
            Map<String, InnerEntity> typedResult = parseJsonToTypedMap(JSON_SOURCE);
    
            System.out.println("Typed result:");
            for (Map.Entry<String,JsonTest.InnerEntity> entity : typedResult.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Element Name: " + entity.getKey());
                System.out.println("Element Values: " + entity.getValue().toString());
                System.out.println("**********************************************");
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Untyped result:");
            Map<String,Object> untypedResult = parseJsonToNotTypedMap(JSON_SOURCE);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entity : untypedResult.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Element Name: " + entity.getKey());
                System.out.println("Element Values: " + entity.getValue().toString());
                System.out.println("**********************************************");
            }
        
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Code. Foreach "RandomText" it will create an InnerEntity-Object.

```
 final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            mapper.readTree(JSON).fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> {
                try {
                    final InnerEntity innerEntity = mapper.readValue(entry.getValue().traverse(), InnerEntity.class);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    //handle ex
                }
            });
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            //handle ex
        }
```